# Using `fancyhdr` with two pagestyles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am writing a long article but still with the `article` class.

I want to redefine my headings using this preambule :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{toc}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\scshape\nouppercase{Table Of Contents}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\fancypagestyle{main}{
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ - #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ - #1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark }}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark }}}
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 pt}
}

\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
\begin{document}


\pagestyle{toc}

\tableofcontents

\clearemptydoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{main}

\section{Introduction}
Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla. Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.Bla bla bla bla.

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}
\newpage 
\end{document}
```

But latex does not want to give me the correct headings when I call `\pagestyle{main}`.

> How can I correct my code to do what I want ?

Thank you in advance.

**PS.** I am using Sharelatex.

Comment: Your code isn't compilable -- the `#1` should read `##1` in your `main` pagestyle definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\renewcommand` of a macro with parameters within some other command inevitably requires `##1` instead of `#1`.

This error caused compilation failure, perhaps `sharelatex` catches this -- anyway, I get two different page styles using the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{toc}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE]{\scshape\nouppercase{Table Of Contents}}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{main}{%
  \fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\color{blue} \thesection\ - ##1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ - ##1}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark }}}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark }}}
  \fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{\newpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}}
\begin{document}


\pagestyle{toc}

\tableofcontents

\clearemptydoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% INTRODUCTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{main}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}

\section{Test Section}

\subsection{First sub section}
\subsection{Second one }
\subsection{Third one}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't see that there were a mistyped ##1 .. Your code is functional but there is one last thing : when a section is starting at the middle of a page there is no headings. Is it normal ?

Comment: @JohnMarjan: I'll check later on -- it's late here. I would say that is normal, yes. It also depends on the `left/right` settings.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. @Christian Hupfer By the way,I redefined `leftmark` and `rightmark` because I didn't succeed in trying to write directly `\fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize{ \thesubsection \ - \scshape\nouppercase{\subsectionmark}}}`
If there is a solution this way I would like to know it :)

Comment: @JohnMarjan: You accepted the answer already, shall I still investigate or is the cause not needed any longer?

Comment: yes I am still interested in your further investigations ! But I also accepted the answer because you aswered it quite well even if I think we could find a better way without redefining `leftmark` and `rightmark` :)